# How to make an image translucent in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an image in iOS.The image is not too big.Now when i am showing that image as profile pic now i also want to show that profile image as background of current screen with translucent effect.Here translucent is i have seen in iPhone & iPad[![enter image description here][1]][1]. 
I have tried below code

```
imageView.alpha=0.3f;
```

but this does not make the image translucent.

Please tell how can i do this?

Comment: do you have any sample code of this design? I didn't get the question

Comment: see i have my image as profile images now i want put my profile image as background with translucent effect so my blurred gradient image will visible as background.@engmahsa

Answer (score 4):

To make image translucent you can use visual effect like this

```
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];

visualEffectView.frame = self.YOURIMAGEVIEW.bounds;
[self.YOURIMAGEVIEW addSubview:visualEffectView];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imageView.opaque = NO;
imageView.alpha=0.3f;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `UIVibrancyEffect` and `UIVisualEffectView`

What does `Alpha` do is that it gives you transparency levels being 0 low to 1 high.

You can achieve the required effect through this:

```
// Create the vibrancy effect - to be added to the blur
let vibrancyEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurEffect)
let vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancyEffect)

//Add your contentview as subview
vibrancyEffectView.contentView.addSubview(contentView)
blurEffectView.contentView.addSubview(vibrancyEffectView)

//Then add the blurEffectView to your view hierarchy to display it:
containerView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Checkout for details: [UIVisualEffects](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios8-day-by-day-day-3-uivisualeffects)